# Current density in an ideal PN junction diode

Tags: current, diodes, semiconductors, charge, pn-junction

[image]

I found that the current density is as above.

The first question is: the logic is that when there is no external voltage applied, the diffusion current cancels the drift current. But there are four types of currents as far as I know. (1) hole diffusion current at P region, (2) electron drift current at P region (3), electron diffusion current at N region, (4) hole drift current at N region.

However, in qualitatively explaining the sign of the current, e.g. in reverse bias, we simply say that the drift current is greater than the diffusion current and they aren't equal so they don't cancel out anymore. But there are four currents, and I have literally no idea what is what. Is there any clear equation about this?

The second question is: why do we not take into account the majority carrier current when we are calculating and deriving the following formula?

$$i_D = I_0(\exp \frac{qV}{kT} - 1)$$

Answer (score 1):

> when there is no external voltage applied, the diffusion current cancels the drift current.

Yes.

> there are four types of currents as far as I know. (1) hole diffusion current at p region (2) electron drift current at p region (3) electron diffusion current at n region (4) hole drift current at n region.

There are multiple ways one can categorise different sorts current. However, the above way does not include *all* current. For example, holes can diffuse in the n region as well. There lifetime is shorter than in the p region, but they can diffuse nevertheless. So, there is a problem with your categorisation.

One way to categorise might be

1. electron drift current
2. electron diffusion current
3. hole drift current
4. hole diffusion current.

If one wanted to localise these currents, one way to describe the regions in a diode would be

a) the quasi-neutral p-doped region
b) the p-doped depletion region
c) the n-doped depletion region
d) the quasi-neutral n-doped region

The electric field in the quasi-neutral regions is very small, so drift current is often treated as vanishing in those regions.

The electric field in the depletion regions is large, and drift current generally dominates diffusion current in that region, so diffusion current is often treated as vanishing in that region.

Holes in the n-doped region are called minority carriers. Electrons in the p-doped region are also minority carriers. The lifetime of minority carriers is smaller than that of majority carriers. In some cases, we may treat minority carrier current as negligible, but many mathematical derivations of p-n junction behaviour explicitly depend upon minority carrier current, so beware of neglecting it willy-nilly.

But that brings us to another way of categorising currents, i.e. minority-carrier current, and majority-carrier current.

> But there are four currents and I have literally no idea what is what. Is there any clear equation about this?

I'm going to answer the next question, and hopefully this question will be taken care of in the process.

> The second question is, why do we not take into account the majority carrier current when we are calculating and deriving the formula

> $$i_D = I_0(\exp \frac{qV}{kT} - 1)$$

Perhaps surprisingly, the bottleneck for equilibrium current in a diode is the rate at which minority carriers can be removed from the boundary separating the depletion zone (also called space charge region) and the quasi-neutral region. The higher the rate at which minority carriers can be removed from that area, the higher the rate that majority carriers can cross the depletion zone and become minority carriers.

So, how are minority carriers removed after being injected across the quasi-neutral region? In a diode, this is primarily through diffusion. The rate of diffusion is proportional to the negative of the gradient/derivative of the carrier density. Since excess minority carriers tend to recombine as they cross a quasi-neutral region, the excess minority carrier density declines exponentially in those regions. Since the excess minority carrier density declines exponentially, its derivative (with respect to distance from the depletion zone) also decays exponentially. Thus, from the minority carrier density at the boundary of the depletion zone, we can calculate the rate of diffusion of the minority carriers, which is (approximately) the current density, and from that we can calculate the total current of that type of carrier. Performing the calculation for both types of carriers allows us to calculate their sum, which is the total current through the diode.

It turns out that (in Shockley's original model of the diode at least)

$$P_n = P_{n0}e^{\frac{V}{V_T}}$$

where

\$P_n\$ is the concentration of holes in the N-doped region,

\$P_{n0}\$ is the concentration of holes in the N-doped region when there is zero bias voltage applied across the diode, and

\$V_T\$ is the thermal voltage (approximately 26 mV at room temperature)

The *excess* hole concentration is

$$\delta P_n = P_n - P_{n0} = P_{n0}\left(e^{\frac{V}{V_T}}-1\right)$$

So,

$$I_p \propto \left(e^{\frac{V}{V_T}}-1\right)$$

and similarly,

$$I_n \propto \left(e^{\frac{V}{V_T}}-1\right)$$

So

$$I = I_p + I_n \propto \left(e^{\frac{V}{V_T}}-1\right)$$

and giving the name \$I_0\$ to the constant of proportionality,

$$I = I_0 \left(e^{\frac{V}{V_T}}-1\right)$$

Which is the original Shockley Diode Equation (or the equation, as modified by Bill Pfann with an ideality factor of 1).